# Skip a viewcontroller with delegates

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates, viewcontroller

i'm turning around for days.
I've got a hierarchy of 3 ViewControllers.

Start in VC1, from there you can load VC2. In VC2 you can load VC3.

My navigation works fine VC1->VC2->VC3 and the same backwards.

VC3 allows the user to go back to VC1.

I wonder if it's possible to tell VC3 that VC1 is now it's delegate.
It would work fine with VC2 but I'd like to use the datas saved in VC3 in VC1.

Answer (score 2):

Create a delegate to pass value from one class to another.
Then set delegate in both VC1 and VC2 where VC1 recieves from VC2 and VC2 recieves from VC3

Then call for delegate from VC3 and pass value to VC2 .In VC2 the called method implement the invocation of its delegate to VC1 and the value is there in vc1

```
VC3-->del-->VC2-->del->VC1
```

Answer (score 0):

If VC1 is the delegate of VC2, you could just assign VC2's delegate property to the delegate property of VC3

In your VC2 @implementation before VC3 is pushed onto the navigation stack:

```
vc3Instance.delegate = self.delegate
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a weak property called 'master' for example in each view controller and make it point to the view controller that presented it. Once you do that, you can then reach VC1 (and all it's data) from VC3 in the following way:

```
VC1ViewController *vc1 = self.master.master;
```